# background video auto play not working on chrome for the first time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

i use elementor section background video. i unmute this the video useing this code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var heroBackgroundVideo = document.querySelector('#myVideo div video.elementor-html5-video');
    
    // Set the video to not be muted (sound on)
    heroBackgroundVideo.muted = false;
    
    // Set the volume to 1 (maximum volume)
    heroBackgroundVideo.volume = 1;
});
```

it works fine. but the problem is when someone visite the site first time the auto play not working. but when reload means secound time visit the site it working fine.

i mean only auto play not working for the first time .
the video is not mute.
I need the solution in javascript code.
thanks

Comment: This is about the user's consent, not your code. Chrome makes sure you cannot spam them with noisy intrusive videos without any warning. You can read their policy online

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Comment: is there any code i can overcome that?

Comment: i am new in this field as i saw the document only mute video auto play will work. But i need to auto play working otherwise video will be no meaning. Please check my site https://experteaseai.com/ . so please if there any solution please tell me as i am new

Comment: Why do you think there is some secret magic answer? The information we gave you is correct. You may not spam users with noisy video without their agreement (either implicit or explicit). It's rude, inconsiderate and also problematic in other ways. The browser is actually helping you- no-one wants to be bombarded the moment they visit your site, without expecting it. It will only annoy them in most cases. You'll just have to wait for them to interact with your site before you can show the video. Why not be polite and let the user choose when to start playing it, at their convenience??